# How Split Json with oracle 19

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

Is there a way to take out part of a json?

I just want the `common` object without `zona` and `central`.

I have the following table

```
   CREATE TABLE FB_TAB 
      ( COL CLOB COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP, 
    ID NUMBER, 
    TYPE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP, 
    COLOR VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP, 
    AMOUNT NUMBER, 
    APP VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) COLLATE USING_NLS_COMP, 
     CONSTRAINT JSON_CON_1 CHECK (col IS JSON) ENABLE
      )
```

and its insert

```
insert into fb_tab 
values('
{"common":{"contrato":{"id":"1","codigo":"054AKSDJ","nombre":"BUCLE"},"servicio":"","actividad":"Apertura","tipo_actividad":"BAJA","numero_administrativo":"","estado_origen":"Pendiente","provincia":{"id":"24","nombre":"León"},"aplicacion_origen":{"id":"1","nombre":"VISORD"},"zona":{"pais":"ES","cliente":"TL","div_geo":"2410002"},"central":{"codigo":"2410002","nombre":"Leon-Torre"},"clave":{"act_domiciliaria":"","prioridad":""}},"app_log":{"app_name":"client_mobile"}}
', 23, 'Ball', 'Red', 15, 'Mobile');
commit;
```

**I want to get the next JSON as a result**

```
{"Type":"Ball","Color":"Red","App":"Mobile","Amount":"15","my_json":{"contrato":{"id":"1","codigo":"054AKSDJ","nombre":"BUCLE"},"servicio":"","actividad":"Apertura","tipo_actividad":"BAJA","numero_administrativo":"","estado_origen":"Pendiente","provincia":{"id":"24","nombre":"León"},"aplicacion_origen":{"id":"1","nombre":"VISORD"},"clave":{"act_domiciliaria":"","prioridad":""}}}
```

I'm trying with this query

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
    'Type' value to_char(a.Type),
    'Color' value to_char(a.Color),
    'App' value to_char(a.App),
    'Amount' value to_char(a.Amount),
    'my_json' VALUE treat ( JSON_QUERY(a.col, '$.common' WITHOUT WRAPPER) as json )
)
--into json_output
FROM FB_TAB a
where a.id = :id;
```

but my actual result is this

```
{"Type":"Ball","Color":"Red","App":"Mobile","Amount":"15","my_json":{"contrato":{"id":"1","codigo":"054AKSDJ","nombre":"BUCLE"},"servicio":"","actividad":"Apertura","tipo_actividad":"BAJA","numero_administrativo":"","estado_origen":"Pendiente","provincia":{"id":"24","nombre":"León"},"aplicacion_origen":{"id":"1","nombre":"VISORD"},"zona":{"pais":"ES","cliente":"TL","div_geo":"2410002"},"central":{"codigo":"2410002","nombre":"Leon-Torre"},"clave":{"act_domiciliaria":"","prioridad":""}}}
```

I don't want to see `zona` and `central`

Is there a way to do this ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake inside the JSON you're trying to insert into the table

Here's the revised insert statement

*I've broke it down in pieces trying to fix it, feel free to "unwrap" it in a single line*

```
insert into fb_tab 
values('
{"common":
    {"contrato":{"id":"1","codigo":"054AKSDJ","nombre":"BUCLE"},
     "servicio":"",
     "actividad":"Apertura",
     "tipo_actividad":"BAJA",
     "numero_administrativo":"",
     "estado_origen":"Pendiente",
     "provincia":{"id":"24","nombre":"León"},
     "aplicacion_origen":{"id":"1","nombre":"VISORD"},
     "clave":{"act_domiciliaria":"","prioridad":""}
    },
 "zona":{"pais":"ES","cliente":"TL","div_geo":"2410002"},
 "central":{"codigo":"2410002","nombre":"Leon-Torre"},
 "app_log":{"app_name":"client_mobile"}
}',
23, 'Ball', 'Red', 15, 'Mobile');
```

Basically you were placing `clave` after `central` and closing it with two curly brackets (`}`) making the `common` to include `zona` and `central`, that you were trying to exclude from the result of the query.

Now when you query the table

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT (
    'Type' value to_char(a.Type),
    'Color' value to_char(a.Color),
    'App' value to_char(a.App),
    'Amount' value to_char(a.Amount)
    ,'my_json' VALUE treat ( JSON_QUERY(a.col, '$.common' WITHOUT WRAPPER) as json )
)
FROM FB_TAB a
where a.id = 23;
```

*Removed the `:id` bind to ease the debugging process*

You get the desired result

```
{"Type":"Ball","Color":"Red","App":"Mobile","Amount":"15","my_json":{"contrato":{"id":"1","codigo":"054AKSDJ","nombre":"BUCLE"},"servicio":"","actividad":"Apertura","tipo_actividad":"BAJA","numero_administrativo":"","estado_origen":"Pendiente","provincia":{"id":"24","nombre":"León"},"aplicacion_origen":{"id":"1","nombre":"VISORD"},"clave":{"act_domiciliaria":"","prioridad":""}}}
```